# Slow data transfer between Server 2012 and Windows XP/7 Clients

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows, tcpip, server-message-block

I've installed a new Dell PowerEdge R720 server at a small company which eight workstations. It is running Windows Server 2012 Standard. I've then installed Hyper-V (role) onto the server and created a virtual instance also running 2012 Standard.

An older PE 2950 server is also running (Windows Server 2003). It serves as the Domain Controller, DNS, DHCP, and runs Systech's software for dispatching/mixing. Everything works okay when the Windows XP clients access the software via the PE 2950.

Last night Integra installed the upgraded server software onto the virtualized 2012 instance and we then installed the client on one of the Windows XP machines - the updated client runs dreadfully slow (takes literally 1-2 minutes for each interaction).

We have new Windows 7 machines to replace the Windows XP machines, so we booted up two of them and install the client on them and tried utilizing the new server - both ran dreadfully slow.

It seems also that the new server may have issues with dropping connections. While Integra was logged in remotely they would be occasionally disconnected.

Other symptoms:

1. File transfer from old server to new server was extremely slow.
2. File transfer from new server to workstations is extremely slow.
3. Downloading large files from the internet to new server oftentimes resulted in corrupted (broken) downloads.
4. Using Wireshark I can see the client machine requesting the application file from the server - and doing so over and over again, as if the request is not acknowledged.

Other system info:

1. The network is running a new Dell PowerConnect 2824 switch, all cabling is Cat 5e.
2. I swapped network cables out between the new server and the switch.
3. There are no appreciable errors appearing on any of the switch ports via the PowerConnect web interface.
4. I switched the port the server was plugged into on the PowerConnect 2824.

I suspect that this is a setting related to SMB or TCP/IP offload, etc. but have been unable to find anything that makes a difference thus far...Any ideas?

Comment: Simple stuff first.  Duplex settings on both ends?  Errors on the port?  Latest NIC drivers?  Different NIC?  File transfer between host 2012 and clients (vs using the VM)?

Answer (score 1):

hot fixes that should be applied. Didn't look carefully to see anything that matches your issue but I'd apply most if not all the ones that apply.+

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15576.hyper-v-update-list-for-windows-server-2012.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check for connection issues at the host OS as well. Run your tests on that, and if things come back good, then it's more than likely at the VM-Physical layer. If the host OS is having connection issues, then it is the NIC driver or NIC itself.

I see you've already tested for most of the physical issues from the NIC out, but try the same downloads on the other server to confirm it's not a network-wide issue.